# Calculating eigenvalues from time independent Schrödinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue

We calculate eigenstates by solving the time independent Schrödinger equation. The time independent Schrödinger equation is an energy eigenvalue problem, so we will get energy eigenstates as the solution for the equation.

If I want to calculate, let's say, the angular momentum eigenstates, how will I calculate that with the time independent Schrödinger equation?

Comment: ...why would you try to calculate the angular momentum eigenstates "with the Schrödinger equation", and what do you actually mean by that?

Comment: Don't we use Schrodinger's Equation to calculate the eigen vectors of a system?

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly state, the time independent Schrodinger equation is nothing more than the eigenvalue problem for the hamiltonian (the energy). If you want the eigenvalues of the $i$th component of the angular momentum you have solve the correponding eigenvalue problem:

\begin{equation}
L_i \left|\psi\right> =
l_i \left|\psi\right>
\end{equation}

where $L_i$ is the operator corresponding to that component of the angular momentum, $l_i$ the eigenvalue and $\left|\psi\right>$ the eigenstate.

If you want to understand angular momentum in quantum mechanics I recommend you learning the representation theory of the group $SU(2)$ first, if you haven't done it yet.

Comment: Does the above eigen value problem you stated come from Schrodinger Equation?

Comment: No, its an eigenvalue problem for a totally different operator, so in principle it doesn't have anything to do with the other problem

Comment: Sometimes, when solving the Schrodinger equation, one finds that there are several eigenstates with the same energy eigenvalue. Then you might want to label them. One way of doing it is by solving the angular momentum eigenvalue problem and using as a label their angular momentum eigenvalue. This can be clearly seen in the usual solution for the hydrogen atom

Comment: @sarthak You can use this labeling for hydrogen atom because $L^2$ and $L_z$ commute with Hamiltonian and therefore can have common set of eigenfunctions. If operator doesn't commute with Hamiltonian its eigenfunctions (at least not all) are NOT eigenfunctions of Hamiltonian.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you like to calculate eigenstates of angular momentum?

> There are orbital angular momentum L and spin angular momentum S. They are quantum numbers of an atom in the system, and have integer eigenvalues as a consequence of quantum effects. The total angular momentum J=L+S. If you write Jx,Jy,Jz into ladder operator J+,J- by J+=Jx+iJy, J-=Jx-iJy, it can reach a conclusion on the angular momentum eigenvalues by operator commutation relation:
>
> [image: angular momentum eigenvalue]
>
> where m is the magnetic quantum number, which can be integers from j,j-1,...to -j+1，-j.

There is a solution to angular momentum eigenfunction. It does not seem to start from Schrodinger equation. It uses ladder operator of angular momentum J. If you want to calculate some matrix elements with angular momentum eigenfunctions, maybe the orthogonality and the eigenvalue given in the above equation is more useful.
http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node210.html